# Adjust display brightness to ambient light

Tags: sensor, lcd

Warning: I'm completely new to Raspberry Pi, and not even sure if it's the right solution here.

I'm trying to make a better digital picture frame. Got almost all the way there by just buying a nice flat-bezel 4k display, connecting a Chromecast, and putting a nice picture frame on it. Voila!

But I want it to adjust its brightness in response to ambient light -- and turn itself off when the room is dark. So now I need something to check a light sensor and control screen brightness.

- Video drivers with Raspberry Pi?
- Disassemble the monitor and wire it up with Arduino?
- Off-the-shelf-HDMI-screen-dimming-device?

I would greatly appreciate any recommendations/suggestions/ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> turn itself off when the room is dark. So now I need something to check a light sensor and control screen brightness.

In this part, you need to do the next two steps.

**First.** Buy a `BH1750FVI I2C` sensor and configure this light sensor hardware to the RPi by [this link - *Using the BH1750FVI I2C Digital Light Sensor*](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/03/bh1750fvi-i2c-digital-light-intensity-sensor/).

**Next.** For the brightness control feature, don't concern about any driver. There is a lot of methods to do that, Although, try one that has written in python the same as your light sensor hardware by [this link - *Brightness Controller*](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness/tree/master).
To change the brightness level by command line, try it by this [Github issue](https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness/issues/53):

```
xrandr --output "your connected display name" --brightness "required percentage brightness/100"
```

**Conclusion:**
After all of this, you can get the brightness level of the room when it's dark. Next, convert the value in the standard of your brightness controller. Finally, write a while bash script and run it as a crontab job that checks the value of brightness level then if the light sensor value is "0", turn the brightness level to "0".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand good.

- You have a 4K tv.
- You have a chrome cast connected
- You want an independent way to control the brightness and ON/OFF.

I would look if your tv has a way to control it by serial port or something similar, like this: https://www.openhab.org/addons/bindings/lgtvserial/. If it has it you can build a light sensor with a raspberry pi or Arduino (BH1750FVI I2C as has said M. Rostami) and send commands by serial protocol to your tv to control brightness and ON/OFF.

Comment: Thanks, this is cool! Any idea if there's a list somewhere of which LG monitors have a serial control port? (I looked, but couldn't find one.)

Comment: You can see look here: https://github.com/suan/libLGTV_serial